# JSONObject возвращает null

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Есть php скрипт на сервере

```
<?php
$response = array();

if (isset($_POST['NameFile']) && isset($_POST['PathFile']) && isset($_POST['Tag']) && isset($_POST['Rating']) && isset($_POST['Author']) && isset($_POST['ArrayEditor']) && isset($_POST['ArrayAnswer']))
 {
    $NameFile = $_POST['NameFile'];
    $PathFile = $_POST['PathFile'];
    $Tag = $_POST['Tag'];
    $Rating = $_POST['Rating'];
    $Author = $_POST['Author'];
    $ArrayEditor = $_POST['ArrayEditor'];
    $ArrayAnswer = $_POST['ArrayAnswer'];

    require 'db_connect.php';

    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO file(NameFile, PathFile, Tag, Rating, Author, ArrayEditor, ArrayAnswer) VALUES('$NameFile', '$PathFile', '$Tag', '$Rating', '$Author', '$ArrayEditor', '$ArrayAnswer')");

    if ($result) 
    {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        echo json_encode($response);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} 
else 
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Если сейчас зайти просто по адресу `http://educt.landmarkstd.ru/create_file.php`
То он выведет массив с ошибкой.

Теперь пытаюсь в android создать новую запись

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NameFile", itemList.nameList));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PathFile", "serverFalse"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Tag", itemList.Tag));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Rating", "5.0"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Author", "Fasd"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ArrayEditor", "Test"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ArrayAnswer", "2*2:2*3:2*4"));

            final JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product, "POST", params);

            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            try
            {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1)
                {
                    Log.d("myLog", "Файл успешно добавлен");
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                Log.d("myLog", "Неудалось");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
```

И эта строчка `Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());` Возвращает null, хотя в самой бд запись добавляется.

А это Лог ошибок:

```
 07-21 13:13:12.558 27177-27216/ru.landmarkstd.educt E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-21 13:13:12.569 27177-27216/ru.landmarkstd.educt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                      Process: ru.landmarkstd.educt, PID: 27177
                                                                      Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, iconPack:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, fontPkg:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle}
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at ru.landmarkstd.educt.FunctionalClass.Server$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(Server.java:70)
                                                                          at ru.landmarkstd.educt.FunctionalClass.Server$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(Server.java:42)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

А это `jsonParser`

```
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List params) {

// Making HTTP request
        try {

// check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
// request method is POST
// defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity (params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }
            else if(method == "GET"){
// request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format (params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e ("Buffer Error", "Error converting result"  + e.toString ());
        }

// try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject (json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

// return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: Закройте SQL Injection http://php.net/manual/ru/security.database.sql-injection.php. Просто вы выстовили дырку публично. Если хотите узнать что с вами смогут делат, смотрите http://sqlmap.org/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш сервер отвечает не JSON'ом в ответ на запрос. Вот, что он отвечает:

```
<br />
<b>Deprecated</b>:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in <b>/home/u179140/landmarkstdru/educt/db_connect.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
{"success":1,"message":"Product successfully created."}
```

Он в ответ шлет свой warning перед JSON'ом

Comment: Спасибо, еще вопрос, он наверное тупой , но как вы смогли получить полный ответ с ошибкой ?

Comment: @Fasd, выполнив POST запрос с вашими параметрами. Я делаю это при помощи расширения для Chrome - Advanced REST client https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-et-na-us-oc-webstrext&utm_medium=et